# Get the facebook user id after like button press

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am adding the like button to a web page and I want to get the Facebook `id` of those who click it.

I know there are some events I can capture with the **`edge.create`** present in the Javascript SDK but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you can't get the user's `ID` unless and until user has authorized your application to get it. There is no way to get the `ID` of the User who has liked your page through present API or SDK. The maximum you can get is is a callback through `event.create` which returns the URL that has been liked, quoting from [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)

> **edge.create** - fired when the user likes something (fb:like). The response parameter to the callback function contains the URL that was liked:"http://www.example.com/article1.php"